# Somthing wrong btween the a+ and the r+ replaces lines

Tags: php

OK so when i use the a+ everything works fine, creates new line and writes the code but when i use the r+ it replaces the first line instead of creating the new line. how can i make it to add a line without replacing it?

When i decided to add the \n (add new line). it would just replace the new line as well, so there is no point adding the \n or \r\n.  Look at thie code

```
$demo = $_POST['demo'];
$text = $_POST['text ']; 
$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];


$fp = fopen('../../include/item.accessory.php', 'r+') or exit("Unable to open file!");
 fseek($fp, 0, SEEK_SET); //MOVES THE CURSOR 0 PLACES FROM START OF THE FILE
 fwrite($fp, $_POST["demo"]);
 fwrite($fp, $_POST["text"]);   
     fwrite($fp, $_POST["name"]);    
     fwrite($fp, $_POST["address"]);    
fclose($fp);
```

Any Idea what i might be doing rung?

Comment: So what is wrong with a+ ??

Comment: There is nothing rung with a+ because that puts the contend at the end of the file with out replacing any text. but considering r+ witch its spost to do witch is  putting the content in the beginning of the accessory.php page without replacing the content of the first line. but instead it replaces the content of the first line  then rewirts the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the docs at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php, specifically:

> 'r+' Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the **beginning** of the file.

and

> 'a+' Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the **end** of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

This tells you this is standard behaviour.

If you wish to add content at the beginning of the file, do:

```
$content = $newcontent.file_get_contents($path_to_file);
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $content);
```

In your specific case you might do:

```
$newcontent = "$_POST[demo] $_POST[text] $_POST[name] $_POST[address]";
$content = $newcontent.file_get_contents($path_to_file);
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $content);
```

Comment: I read it already, its not the answer. r+ shouldn't replace the text in the first row. it should add the text. like a+ dose. i have seen r+ in action there is defiantly a way to do this

Comment: Nope, I do not think it should add text, in fact the already present bytes of the string are replaced by the new ones, not shifted forward, see my edit.

Comment: I tried the code you gave me, it did not work.    $content = $discrip.file_get_contents('../../include/item.accessory.php');
$JustATest = file_put_contents($accessory, $content);
  fwrite($fp, $_POST["$JustATest"]);

Comment: Why did you use `fwrite()` after `file_put_contents()`? I'll edit the answer again to make a clearer example.